# I got Error 500 in android broadcast code getting data for notification asp.net api when i post link on browser it show data in browser

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

```
client.post("http://192.168.10.7:8080/api/Notifications",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {

             System.out.println(response);
                try {
                    // Create JSON object out of the response sent by getdbrowcount
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    System.out.println(obj.get("count"));
                    // If the count value is not zero, call MyService to display notification
                    if(obj.getInt("count") != 0){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        final Intent intnt = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
                        // Set unsynced count in intent data
                        intnt.putExtra("intntdata", "Unsynced Rows Count "+obj.getInt("count"));
                        // Call MyService
                        context.startService(intnt);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Sync not needed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Not working help me "link is correct and working" server also working !

Comment: And http error code 500 is internal server error (unhandled) so you could get some info on 192.168.10.7 logs.

Answer (score 0):

500 is Internal server error, That means something has gone wrong on the website's server, but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.